# Mysql : performance Index on Varchar (100) vs index on date for joining

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

What will perform better if I join a million rows table to equally big table with a varchar 100 length field vs date field. For simplicity consider both column have same number of match.

Comment: Date will perform better, why don't you try it out?

Comment: just want to making sure before start as it I have to prioritize columns to run multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough difference to matter.

Fetching rows takes so much more time than comparing columns that it is not worth worrying about.

If the column is naturally a `DATE`, then use that; if it is naturally a string, then use `VARCHAR(...)`.

If you really have "dates", you should use `DATE` for other reasons:

- Ease of inequality, range, etc, tests
- Lots of functions for picking apart the dates and manipulating them.